# Interface collection member strange behavior during object initialization

Tags: c#, .net, initializer

I run into runtime `NullReferenceException` exception in the following code:

```
public class Container
{
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container() { Items = {"Test"} };
    }
}
```

It's logical that compiller couldn't create interaface instance but I got a runtime exception, not a compile time. I was confused even more when I investigated this behavior further:

```
    var container = new Container() { Items = {} }; //Legal, Items is null after initialization

    var container = new Container() { Items = { "Test" } }; //Legal, throws exception
    container.Items = {}; //Illegal doesn't compile
    container.Items = {"Test"}; //Illegal doesn't compile
```

Is this some kind of bug or I don't understand something?
And I'm using .net framework 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles, because compiler has no knowledge about *is the `List` already initialized somewhere else*. You can make it work by adding initialization into a constructor:

```
public class Container
{
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; }

    public Container()
    {
        Items = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Or changing the property to hide a field, which is initialized when class instance is created:

```
private IList<string> items = new List<string>();
public IList<string> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; }
}
```

Then, `var container = new Container() { Items = { "Test" } };` works just fine.

At runtime `.Add()` method is called for every item in collection initializer group. When property is not initialized with `new List<string>` it has `null` value, and that's why `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

> By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple
>   calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; **the compiler
>   adds the calls**.

Comment: I always thought that `var container = new Container() { Items = { "Test" } }` creates collection and adds items to collection, I was wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

you didn't initialize the `List`

```
  var container = new Container() { Items = new List<string>() { "Test" } };
```

By the way the below is legal as for the compiler there is nothing wrong with it (syntax is correct,etc)

```
var container = new Container() { Items = {} };
```

but because the compiler doesn't know that `Items` list has not been initialized (you are not passing any item in the collection initializator `{}`) the `.Add` method won't be called on the `List` and the run-time won't know that the `Items` object is null

On the other hand  the below is legal for the compiler but it throws an exception at run time because you try  to initialize the the list passing an item (it is correct for the compiler for the same reason explained above) so when the run time will call the `.Add` method behind the scene, it will throw a null reference exception because `Items` has not been initialized

```
 var container = new Container() { Items = { "Test" } };
```

Comment: I think the question is why the first line - `new Container() { Items = {} };`  is compiling

Comment: With new List it's easy. The main question is why it's even compiling.